# Can't start ruby gem robocop (MAC OS X) -bash: robocop: command not found

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I try start robocop gem, but terminal returns:

```
    -bash: robocop: command not found
```

For example: `bundler gem` works normaly.

What can i do for fix it?

Thank you for advice.

It's my gem list:

```
    Air-Dmitri:rb_dev dk$ gem list

    *** LOCAL GEMS ***

    ast (2.3.0)
    bigdecimal (1.2.8)
    bundler (1.13.6)
    bundler-unload (1.0.2)
    byebug (9.0.6)
    coderay (1.1.1)
    did_you_mean (1.0.0)
    executable-hooks (1.3.2)
    gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
    io-console (0.4.5)
    json (1.8.3)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    minitest (5.8.3)
    net-telnet (0.1.1)
    parser (2.3.1.4)
    power_assert (0.2.6)
    powerpack (0.1.1)
    pry (0.10.4)
    pry-byebug (3.4.0)
    psych (2.0.17)
    rainbow (2.1.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rdoc (4.2.1)
    rubocop (0.45.0)
    ruby-progressbar (1.8.1)
    rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
    rvm (1.11.3.9)
    slop (3.6.0)
    test-unit (3.1.5)
    unicode-display_width (1.1.1)
```

ruby -v ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]

gem -v 2.5.1

rvm -v rvm 1.27.0 (latest) ...

Comment: Where are you trying the command from? You have to be within a ruby project directory I think for it to work...

Comment: Trying in dir "rb_dev" it's contains .rb file

Comment: I think the problem is that you are misspelling it — the command is **rubocop** *not* robocop; it's easy to make a typo on that, especially considering the name...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps try r**u**bocop, not r**o**bocop

Comment: Yes misspelling. It's true

Comment: It's 2019 and I just made the same mistake, googled it and ended up here :)